# The 'MarkdownEditorPackage' did not load correctly

Tags: visual-studio-2019, visual-studio-extensions

After installing the MarkDown editor plugin for Visual Studio 2019, when I open my project, Visual Studio crashes with the following message «The 'MarkdownEditorPackage' did not load correctly».

I tried reinstalling the extension but it didn't solve my problem :/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I deleted the .vs folder and my problem is solved :)